# Неправильное скалирование шрифта

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть 2 страницы. [Первая](http://bm.let120.net/node/uvelichenie-uznavaemosti-i-pribylnosti) и [вторая](http://bm.let120.net/node/uvelichenie-prodazh-cherez-internet). Если в мобильном эмуляторе уменьшать ширину, то шрифт заголовков на 1ой странице начинает неправильно себя вести. А именно, он увеличивается. На второй странице этого не происходит, хотя стили одинаковые (делал вначале 1ую страницу, а потом уже добавлял селекторы 2ой). Объясните, пожалуйста, почему такое происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

для избежания данной проблемы.

Если решение выше не принесет плодов попробуйте писать размеры в `Viewport Sized Typography`: [**Подробнее**](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: Не подходит. Не будет адаптивной версии сайта. Он должен открываться на мобильном устройстве так, как открывается сейчас. 
2ой вариант тоже не помогает.